# Change FASTA file headers

Tags: shell, awk, sed, fasta

please, I would like to modify my FASTA file headers:

```
>NCI-14_00510 23S ribosomal RNA
>JT413_15400 23S ribosomal RNA
>JT410_15270 23S ribosomal RNA
```

to

```
>NCI-14 23S ribosomal RNA
>JT413 23S ribosomal RNA
>JT410 23S ribosomal RNA
```

Please could somebody help?

Many thanks

Comment: `tr '_' ' ' `  may be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed '/^>/s/\([^_]*\)_[^ ]*\(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

In a nutshell:

- `/^>`: for lines starting with `>`, …
- … `s/‹a›/‹b›/`: substitute `‹a›` with `‹b›`, where

  - `\([^_]*\)`: a group that matches multiple characters except `_`
  - `_[^ ]*`: `_` followed by multiple non-whitespace characters
  - `\(.*\)`: a group matching the rest; and
- `\1\2`: substitute all that by just the contents of the two match groups.